# Mongoose aggreagate with group not working

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

In my Node.JS API, it is possible to order and get menus. The structure of an ordered menu looks like the following (the **main schema** is the **orderMenuSchema**; **menuItemSchema** is for the subdocument-array with ordered items):

```
var menuItemSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    itemId: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        required: true
    },
    prepared: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: false
    },
    finished: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: false
    },
    timestamp: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date()
    }
}, {_id: false})

var orderMenuSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    orderId: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        required: true
    },
    menuId: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        required: true
    },
    items: {
        type: [menuItemSchema],
        required: true,
        validate: menuItemsCheck
    },
    finished: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: false
    },
    timestamp: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date()
    }  
})
```

### Example Data:

```
{
   "_id":"5d2333a1841a0e4ef05873d0",
   "finished":false,
   "timestamp":"2019-07-08T12:14:04.000Z",
   "menuId":"5d189ffdbe02ef0b00b22370",
   "items":[
      {
         "prepared":false,
         "finished":false,
         "timestamp":"2019-07-08T12:14:04.000Z",
         "itemId":"5d189ffdbe02ef0b00b2236d"
      },
      {
         "prepared":false,
         "finished":false,
         "timestamp":"2019-07-08T12:14:04.000Z",
         "itemId":"5d189ffdbe02ef0b00b2236e"
      },
      {
         "prepared":false,
         "finished":false,
         "timestamp":"2019-07-08T12:14:04.000Z",
         "itemId":"5d189ffdbe02ef0b00b2236f"
      }
   ],
   "orderId":"5d2333a1841a0e4ef05873c3",
   "__v":0
}
```

**Whether an item is prepared or not is stored in the prepared field of the menuItem.**

Each menu has multiple items to choose from, and the user is able to have only some items - that's why the orderMenuSchema has an array of subdocuments called "items" in which **only the ordered items are stored**.

> Now I would like to get all unprepared menus, group them by the menuID
>   and then group them by the itemID - everything with a Mongoose
>   aggregation.

So, I think I need two groupings: The first one by the **menuId**, the second one by the **itemId**.

Furthermore, I would like to know how many of each item are unprepared - so after grouping by the menuId, **I need to get a count of all unprepared items**

### Expected Output:

I thought of something like this:

```
{
   "result":[
      {
         "menuID":"tastefulMenu123",
         "items":[
            {
               "itemId":"noodlesoop123",
               "unpreparedCount":13
            },
            {
               "itemId":"tastyBurger123",
               "unpreparedCount":2
            },
            {
               "itemId":"icecoldIce123",
               "unpreparedCount":20
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

There will be an array of subdocuments, one subdocument for each menuId. Each subdocument than has an array of items in which the itemID as well as the unpreparedCount are stored.

### What I already tried (not working):

```
OrderMenu.aggregate([
        {$unwind: "$items"},
        { $project: { prepared: 1, itemId: 1} },
        { $match: {
            prepared: false,
            timestamp: {
                $gte: today,
                $lt: tomorrow 
            }    
        }},
        { $group: {
            _id: {menuId: '$menuId', itemId: '$itemId'},
            count: { $sum: 1 }
        }}
    ]).then(result => {
        console.log(result)
        return Promise.resolve(result)
    }).catch(error => {
        console.log(error)
        return Promise.reject(500)
    })
```

### Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: It would be good if you show some sample documents which can produce your expected output

Comment: @Ashh what do you mean? My question includes an "expected output"?

Comment: @Ashh I now added a sample document. Is that what you meant?

Comment: Yes. But should be in JSON format. Not images.

Comment: @Ashh one second :)

Comment: @Ashh I now provided JSON Data :)